# Is this the right algorithm to calculate similiarity?

Tags: java, algorithm, statistics, correlation, similarity

I am writing a program that based on the ratings of products given by Clients, it will recommend them other Clients. Values range from 1 to 5.

So lets say I have clientA who has rated 5 products a, b, c, d, e with these values:
[3, 4, 2, 4, 3]

ClientB has rated these same 5 products like this: [5, 4, 2, 3, 3]

Now im looking for an algorithm that checks how close the ratings are for each product. Like for product a compares 3 to 5, product b 4 to 4 ect. And based on the final value i decide whether to recomment clientB to clientA or not.

I came across the Pearsons Correlation which has a library in java and its seems fitting but im worried that its like taking the average of each array somehow and comparing them, instead of analyzing each product a&a' ratings to one another and giving a final overall estimation.

I have read articles, but I just cant understand linear correlation. Can someone confirm whether this Pearsons Correlation is the right one in my case?

Answer (score 0):

*similarRatio* variable means how many points away between reviews count as a match (0 = equal)

*similarPercent* variable means the percentage of matches needed to become a recommendation (0.5 = 50%)

```
private static boolean shouldRecomend(int similarRatio, double similarPercent, int[] clientA, int[] clientB) {
        int similarCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < clientA.length; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(clientA[i] - clientB[i]) <= similarRatio) {
                similarCount++;
            }
        }
        if (clientA.length * similarPercent <= similarCount) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
```

Client arrays should be the same lenght